# How to publish Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

How to publish the following Shiny code, in which I use my package.

I am not sure, how to publish the following structure's shiny Code. 
Is it sufficient to upload it as a function?
Or I need to divide the following code into ui.R and sever.R and the other materials?

Note that the following function has been already published in my package on CRAN.

```
fit_GUI_dashboard <- function(
  DF=data.frame(h=c( 97L,   32L,   31L),f=c( 1L ,  14L,   74L )),
  NL.max=1111,
  NI.max=1111,
  MCMC.chains.max=4


){


  outdir <- system.file("myapp", package = "MyPakcage")

  if (outdir == "") {
    stop("Could not find myapp. Try re-installing `MyPakcage`.", call. = FALSE)
  }



  ui1 <- shinydashboard::dashboardPage(

  )#dashboardPage






  server1 <- shiny::shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  })

  ## run app
  shiny::runApp(list(ui=ui1, server=server1))
  return(invisible())
}
```

---

**Publish means the following:**

[image]

**I try it, but unknown error occurs and UI is correctly arranged but the program is not running as the following image:**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "publish"?

Comment: Thank you @Aurèle,  "publish" means such as the above image. I am not sure but it is for the people who do not have R environment. I have struggled, but,... I cannot upload well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are publishing your apps to your [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io) account, so you can check the console logs for your remote R session by logging into your application dashboard on the shinyapps.io site.

After logging in and selecting your application, click on the "Logs" button towards the upper-righthand section of the screen (visible in below screenshot). The log will tell you exactly what the error is: it may be a referenced variable that's not loaded by your script, a package dependency that needs to be explicitly installed on your remote server, or something else entirely. The error message will give you more information.

[image: shinyapps.io application dashboard]

Comment: Thank you, I found `Logs` button. So,... I try to remove errors.